# .backward() function in PyTorch trying to backward through the graph a second time

Tags: python, machine-learning, pytorch, reinforcement-learning

```
def train_step(self, state, action, reward, next_state, game_over):
    state = torch.tensor(state, dtype=torch.float)
    next_state = torch.tensor(next_state, dtype=torch.float)
    action = torch.tensor(action, dtype=torch.long)
    reward = torch.tensor(reward, dtype=torch.float)

    if len(state.shape) == 1:
        state = torch.unsqueeze(state, 0)
        next_state = torch.unsqueeze(next_state, 0)
        action = torch.unsqueeze(action, 0)
        reward = torch.unsqueeze(reward, 0)
        game_over = (game_over, )

    # Bellman Equation
    pred = self.model(state)



    target = pred.clone()
    for idx in range(len(game_over)):
        Q_new = reward[idx]
        if not game_over[idx]:
            Q_new = reward[idx] + self.gamma * torch.max(self.model(next_state[idx]))

        target[idx][torch.argmax(action[idx]).item()] = Q_new

        # Loss Equation
        self.optimizer.zero_grad()
        loss = self.criterion(target, pred)
        loss.backward() # FIXME

        self.optimizer.step()
```

Creating a reinforced learning algorithm to play snake game. Everything else works but this one issue prevents the code from working after the snake dies for the first time.

Comment: Is it on purpose calling `.backward()` without model forwarding?

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Comment: You are calling model twice: pred = self.model(state) and Q_new = .... You have to use no_grad on first one. Also, when the game is over, model is not called but you are still calculating loss.